# Separate input file into three columns and sort it by the third column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

So far I have my script (script.sh) as:

```
#!/bin/bash/

BEGIN {  
        print "Author    Name of Book     ISBN"  
        print "------    ------------     ----"  
}  
{ printf "%-9s &s\n", 1$, 2$, 3$ }  
END
```

Then I run the command:

```
sort -k 3,3 INPUTFILE.INPUT | awk -f script.sh
```

Nothing above is working as needed.

Also as a note, the input file has data separated by commas. I also have to use a "loop" which I'm hoping the awk command is doing.

Comment: First, your shebang should be `#!/bin/bash`. The trailing slash would denote the directory `/bin/bash/` and not the `bash` executable. Provide a sample of the data in `INPUTFILE.INPUT, the output that you are getting, and the output that you are expecting. It's almost impossible to troubleshoot without this information.

Comment: @NasirRiley I don't think the shebang matters here - since the OP is passing the whole thing to `awk -f` (which will just treat it as a comment)

Comment: Hi yes sorry. The input file has 7 rows. Example; author,name of book,isbn

Comment: @trevor Provide us an example of it. What is the output that you are getting and what is expected?

Comment: im getting syntax error in my script where the commas are separating 1$, 2$, 3$

Comment: @steeldriver That's true in this case but I'm just remarking on it for future reference in case he actually wants to run it as a script. The important thing is the output that he's getting and what he's expecting and the contents of the input file.

Comment: @trevor What error? You aren't providing enough information. What are you expecting?

Comment: @trevor there are MANY errors; for example fields in awk are denoted `$1`, `$2`,`$3` etc NOT `1$`,`2$`,`3$`. Also AFAIK `&s` is not a valid format specifier for printf. And if your data is comma delimited you need to account for that in both `sort` (via the `-t` option) and `awk` (e.g. use `-F,` to set the input separator).

Comment: I have switched the dollar sign. i have added -t to sort. the output im getting reads: end blocks must have an action part

Comment: In awk, `END` doesn't merely stand for the end of a program: it is a *rule* that needs a matching action block like `END { do stuff }`. You don't need it here.

Comment: I have been searching around. I found that : sed 's/,/|/g' inputfile.input     --- this does everything i need it to do except sort. will awk -f fix that?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here, some that will generate errors, and other that are just typos or the result of misunderstandings:

1. The `#!`-line can be removed, or it should say

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/awk -f
   ```

   (or whatever the location of `awk` is on your system).  With the above `#!`-line, you do not have to call the script with `awk -f` on the command line but could use `./script.awk` directly, if it's executable.  With no `#!`-line, you do need to use `awk -f` on the command line.
2. To reference the value in a particular field in the input data, use `$n` where `n` is the field number that you are referring to, not `n$`.
3. The `printf` formatting string has only one format placeholder, but you are giving it three pieces of data. It also lacks parentheses around its arguments.
4. The `END` block may be removed.
5. If the input has field delimiters such as `,` or `|` instead of being delimited on whitespace (spaces or tabs), you will have to tell `awk` about this by using e.g. `awk -F ','` or `awk -F '|'`, or by setting the variable `FS` to the appropriate character in the `BEGIN` block.  Otherwise the script will split the input records wrongly.

This leaves us with the script (`script.awk`):

```
BEGIN {
    fmt = "%-15s\t%-15s\t%-15s\n"
    printf(fmt, "Author", "Name of Book", "ISBN")  
    printf(fmt, "------", "------------", "----")  
}

{ printf(fmt, $1, $2, $3) }
```

I took the liberty to introduce a format string that formats each of the three tab-delimited fields as a left-justified string.  Each fields gets 15 characters of space.  You may easily tweak this by changing `fmt` in the `BEGIN` block.

The invocation would be

```
sort -t ',' -k 3,3 INPUTFILE.INPUT | awk -F ',' -f script.awk
```

Here, it is assumed that the data in the file is comma-separated (and the `sort` command has been changed accordingly).